# Lists of anime in plaintext

Tags: resources

I'm trying to find lists of anime by genre in plaintext. Basically, the issue is that every anime list I can find online (MAL, ANN, Anime Planet) is stylised in some way, which isn't conducive to copy-pasting. I'd like the lists in plaintext.

Comment: this question belongs on stack overflow or power user. That said, you might want to try using this -> https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/02/17/portia-alternative-to-kimono/

Comment: what do you mean by copy-pasting? is xml/json ok? then you could also look at apis of different sites, like myanimelist.

Comment: @ton.yeung:  No, this question does **not** belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: MAL's API was remarkably useless as of a year or two ago. It might've improved since DeNA bought them, though.

Comment: it may be possible to create a PHP Unit Script to run on Selenium to loop though every page of say MAL's anime list and run Javascript script to extract the data from the page and generate a sort of database only containing titles and genre which then could be used to generate a copy and paste friendly list....but weather someone will do that or not is another question

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a small script that operates on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Anime_and_manga_by_genre) that Arcane provided.

```
var anime = "";

$('#mw-pages li').each(function(key, value)
{
    anime += ($(this).text() + '\n');
});

// Credit to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18197341/3571997
function download(filename, text) 
{
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

download($('#firstHeading').text() + '.txt', anime);
```

**How to use:**

1. Start a browser that can inject JavaScript into a page (I will use Google Chrome for this demonstration).
2. Navigate to a category on the Wikipage (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Fantasy_anime_and_manga).
3. Open the developer console (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and click on the console tab.
4. Copy and paste the script in there and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. You should now receive a text file with all of the anime of this genre.

**Remarks:**

- It also lists manga, visual novels etc.
- Not user friendly.

I shall try to update (and turn it into a userscript) whenever I have more time on my hands.

Answer (score 2):

AniDB has api with their titles in single xml
https://wiki.anidb.net/w/API

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animetitles>
    <anime aid="1">
        <title type="short" xml:lang="en">CotS</title>
        <title xml:lang="fr" type="official">Crest of the Stars</title>
        <title xml:lang="en" type="official">Crest of the Stars</title>
        <title type="official" xml:lang="pl">Crest of the Stars</title>
        <title type="syn" xml:lang="cs">Hvězdný erb</title>
        <title type="main" xml:lang="x-jat">Seikai no Monshou</title>
        <title xml:lang="x-jat" type="short">SnM</title>
        <title type="syn" xml:lang="zh-Hans">星界之纹章</title>
        <title type="official" xml:lang="ja">星界の紋章</title>
    </anime>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia to the rescue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Anime_and_manga_by_genre)

I'd start from here. Each genre has the list of Anime/Manga that are tagged for that genre. Seems like the thing you want